# How to start spyder from desktop on LMDE5?

Tags: .desktop, lmde, spyder

I would like to start spyder from a `.desktop` shortcut.

I am unfortunately unable to start it directly from AnacondaNav, as it stops with a `Exit code: 134` message.
As an alternative, I installed spyder using:

```
conda update -n base -c defaults conda  
conda update anaconda  
conda install spyder=5.4.2
```

This lets me start spyder with:

```
conda activate spyder-env
spyder
```

How do I create a `.desktop` file with these commands? 
I have tried copying/altering various other `.desktop` and `.sh` files (with/out #!/bin/bash), but none have worked.

System setup:

- OS: LMDE 5 / elsie
- 5.10.0-21-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.162-1
- Cinnamon 5.6.8
- Python 3.11.2
- conda 23.3.1
- Spyder IDE 5.4.2

Edit:
Tried some suggestions from the comments: 
`(sh -c) conda activate spyder-env; spyder` gives either "There was an error launching the application" or no output at all. 
Adding `conda act...` to `.profile` activates the python env but running `spyder` from the `.desktop` after that does nothing.

Comment: Can you show us some of the things you tried? How does it fail? What happens if you make a .desktop file that executes `conda activate spyder-env; spyder` or `sh -c 'conda activate spyder-env; spyder'`? What happens if you add `conda activate spyder-env` to your `~/.profile` file and then have `spyder` in the .desktop?

Comment: You're welcome, but did they work? Please [edit] your question and answer the things I asked so we know how to help you. We need to see what you tried and how it failed so we don't waste your time, or ours, suggesting solutions you have already discarded.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. See my edit in the text.

Comment: OK, but please show us the actual contents of the `.desktop` file you are using and the _exact_ commands you tried since `(sh -c) conda activate spyder-env; spyder` isn't a valid command. Another option would be to make a script with the two commands and run your script from the .desktop file. But the devil's in the details with this sort of thing, so we will always need to see the _exact_ thing you tried.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was in fact quite simple; adding the full path (in my case `/home/christer/anaconda3/envs/spyder-env/bin/spyder`) to the spyder.sh script solved all problems.
`spyder` can now be started both from the terminal, and by right-clicking the `spyder.sh` file on the desktop, regardless of whether the spyder-env is activated or not.